# NPM invoked on Angular page startup and crashes

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular, iis

We have a couple of ASP.Net + Angular (.Net Core 2.1, Angular5) web pages on the IIS server that suddenly stopped working.

We get "AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: ))".

It seems that it attempts to run npm as the web is launched and it crashes. I tried to install Nodejs on the server and I can see the npm really starts, but crashes with mkdir operation not permitted. Anyway, I don't understand why it's started in the first place.

[image: Server]

When start the same app on local IIS npm is not started and app runs without the problem.

[image: Local]

We can't find what happened on the server. The same apps ran smoothly before.

Many thanks.

Michal

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Colleagues set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = DEVELOPMENT. Changing it back to Production fixed it.